# FxCop/StyleCop equivalent for ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, code-analysis, static-code-analysis

Is there any static code analysis tools for ruby on rails? I am looking for something on the lines of "tests vs code analysis" as well as rules based analysis provided by FxCop.

As an additional feature, an integration with hudson would be cool too.

Answer (score 2):

`rake stats` will give you a simple comparison based on line count. [Rcov](http://eigenclass.org/hiki.rb?rcov) will give you a good picture of your test-coverage. But you should absolutely check out [metric-fu](http://metric-fu.rubyforge.org/)! Includes all kinds of packages, all analysis tools can be run from with a simple `rake metrics:all`, and generates nice reporting ... in short: awesome ;)

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The StyleCop equivalent is called RuboCop:
https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop
There is no exact equivalent for FxCop, but there are some  tools like Scientist, rails_best_practices, Reek etc.